# How to add a library to flutter dependencies

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter and I want to add Fast Android networking library to flutter dependencies and I don't know how to add, anyone, help me, please.

Comment: Check [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#adding-a-package-dependency-to-an-app) out on the official documentation

Comment: You can go to the pubspec.yaml file and add dependencies ,under dependencies and then packages get will do the work.
or you can run flutter pub get in the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the pubspec.yaml file under your root project and add your dependencies/libraries.

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.3 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  path: ^1.8.3
  sqflite: ^2.2.8+4
  # add this line to your dependencies
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  # Enable generation of localized Strings from arb files.
  generate: true

  assets:
    # Add assets from the images directory to the application.
    - assets/images/
    - assets/database/
```

Answer (score 8):

It is very simple to add a package in flutter dependencies. What you need to do is place it under the `dependencies:` inside the **pubspec.yaml** file.

So open the **pubspec.yaml**. You will find this file in root project folder of your flutter app. And do the following to add new dependencies/libraries:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # dependencies come below here
  example_dependency: ^3.2.0+1 // at the end is the version of the depenency
  second_example_dependecy: any // 'any' for any version of the dependecy
```

**To find or discover new libraries** for flutter and dart to help you in building your app you can find flutter and dart packages [here](https://pub.dev/packages/).

Answer (score 4):

To add `http` package to your flutter project, from within a terminal at the project root, just type:

```
flutter pub add http
```

The latest stable version will be used.

For info on options take a look at https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-add